# Выдает ошибку SyntaxError: invalid syntax в условной конструкции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начал изучать питон, начал с программы которая решает квадратное уравнение:

```py
a = float(input("Input A variable: "))
b = float(input("Input B variable: "))
c = float(input("Input C variable: "))

if a != 0 :
    if b != 0 and c != 0:
        if b > 0 and c > 0:            
            print ("Eqation: ", a, "x^2 + ", b, "x +", c, " = 0")

        print ("Decide through discriminant: ")
        print ("D = b^2 - 4ac")
        print ("D = ",b,"^2 - 4","*",a,"*",c," = ",(b**2)," + ",(4*a*c)," = ",(b**2 - (4*a*c)))

        discr = (b**2 - (4*a*c))

        print ("Current value discreminant:", discr)

        if discr > 0:
            b1 = ('-'+ b)
            b1 = float(b)
            x1 = ((b1 + squrt(discr))/(2*a))
            print("x1 = ", x1)
            x2 = ((b1 - squrt(discr))/(2*a))
            print(x2)

        if discr == 0:
            x = float('-'+((b)/(2*a))

        if discr < 0:
            print ("there are no roots on the set of real numbers")

else:
    print("err: A variable not equals 0!")
```

Вначале она берет значения с клавиатуры:

```
a = float(input("Input A variable: "))
b = float(input("Input B variable: "))
c = float(input("Input C variable: "))
```

Дальше идут проверки на то не равна ли переменная А нулю, является ли это полным квадратным уравнением:

```
if a != 0 :
    if b != 0 and c != 0:
        if b > 0 and c > 0:
```

Последнее условное выражение выше будет использоваться для того что-бы в последующем вывести выражение на экран:

```
print ("Eqation: ", a, "x^2 +", b, "x +", c, " = 0")
```

Потом подробно по действиям расписывает нахождение дискриминанта и находит его:

```
print ("Eqation: ", a, "x^2 + ", b, "x +", c, " = 0")
print ("Decide through discriminant: ")
print ("D = b^2 - 4ac")
print ("D = ",b,"^2 - 4","*",a,"*",c," = ",(b**2)," + ",(4*a*c)," = ",(b**2 - (4*a*c)))

discr = (b**2 - (4*a*c))

print ("Current value discreminant:", discr)
```

Далее извлекает корни:

```
if discr > 0:
    b1 = ('-'+ b)
    b1 = float(b)
    x1 = ((b1 + squrt(discr))/(2*a))
    print("x1 = ", x1)
    x2 = ((b1 - squrt(discr))/(2*a))
    print(x2)

if discr == 0:
    x = float('-'+((b)/(2*a))

if discr < 0:
    print ("there are no roots on the set of real numbers")
```

И вот я подхожу к сути вопроса:

```
if discr < 0:
    print("there are no roots on the set of real numbers")
```

При запуске консоль выдаёт ошибку, как я понимаю она ссылается на код выше, сообщение выглядит так:

File "QuadEq.py", line 39
  if discr < 0:
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

В чем может быть проблема?

*P.S. скрипт запускаю на Linux сервере*

Comment: `x = float('-'+((b)/(2*a))` скобки не сбалансированы:( Нужна еще одна закрывающая. Или может лучше так `x = -b/(2*a)`?

Comment: О, отлично заданый толковый вопрос. Плюс от меня. PS. Потом еще будет ошибка в строчке ``b1 = ('-'+ b)``, потому что складывать символы и числа нельзя. Можно решить так ``b1 = ('-'+ str(b))``

Comment: да, и так-же я забыл импортировать модуль math, спасибо, что помогли)

Comment: То самое чувство, когда у тебя в коде другие нашли больше ошибок, чем ты

Answer (score 1):

```
if discr > 0:
            b1 = ('-'+ b)
            b1 = float(b)
            x1 = ((b1 + squrt(discr))/(2*a))
            print("x1 = ", x1)
            x2 = ((b1 - squrt(discr))/(2*a))
            print(x2)
```

Не "squrt", а "sqrt".
И не был импортирован модуль "math".

Answer (score 0):

вот я переписал твой код вроде должен работать

```
from math import sqrt
a = float(input("Input A variable: "))
b = float(input("Input B variable: "))
c = float(input("Input C variable: "))

if a != 0 and b !=0 and c != 0:

    if b > 0 and c > 0:            
        print (f"Eqation: {a}x^2 + {b}x + {c} = 0")

    print ("Decide through discriminant: ")
    print ("D = b^2 - 4ac")
    print (f"D = {b} ^ 2 - 4 * {a} * {c} = {b**2} + {(4*a*c)} = { (b**2) - (4*a*c) }")

    discr = (b**2 - (4*a*c))

    print ("Current value discreminant:", discr)

    if discr > 0:
        b1 = ('-'+ b)
        b1 = float(b)
        x1 = ((b1 + sqrt(discr))/(2*a))
        print("x1 = ", x1)
        x2 = ((b1 - sqrt(discr))/(2*a))
        print(x2)
    elif discr == 0:
        x = float(-b)/(2*a)
    else:
        print ("there are no roots on the set of real numbers")

else:
    print("err: A variable not equals 0!")
```